# Korea Government vs Korean Government?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, compound-adjectives

Simply Question,

As a foreigner, I am really confused when to use Adjective or Noun before Noun.

Which one is correct? I have seen the both of them many times.

- Korea Government vs Korean Government
- Environment Policy vs Environmental Policy.

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does your research show? Can you tell us what you understand and what bothers you most based on your research? Have you tried to search "French Government", "English Government" and "Chinese Government"? Are there "France Government", "England Government" and "China Government" being used?

Comment: It is the Government *that belongs to* Korea; you use the adjective form. **Korean Government**

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrases are:

- Korean Government
- Environmental Policy

You could avoid the adjective form with:

- Government of Korea
- Policy for the environment (or "concerning" or "about" instead of "for")